# `Failed to find data adapter` for numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, keras

I have a model which uses the algorithmic auto encoder to improve the images of the magnetic resonance images (MRI). When I run the steps of the model and arrive in this step:

```py
# Consider increasing epochs for better performance
y = np.asarray(y)
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X, y)
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc}")
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please post a [mre]